# How to know if there is space between argv[0] to argv[1]

Tags: c

My program gets main parameters and my assignment is to check if the user has entered a space between the execution file to the parameters.

- This is an example for someone who hasn't entered space between the `argv[0]` being `HW01` and `argv[1]` being `/n`: `HW01/n`
- But if someone types the line with a space between the file name and the parameters, I need to identify it: `HW01 /n` But the question is: How do I do it?

I've checked if the space is added to the end of `argv[0]` or the the beginning of `argv[1]` but it wasn't there.

I'm using Windows.

Comment: On which OS? On Linux and most POSIX systems, it is the shell which parses the command line (and build an array of `char*` strings, `NULL` terminated).

Comment: Please post your code here in the question, not a convoluted trail.

Comment: And not all your code, but an [SSCCE](http://www,sscce.org) and the desired and actual behavior!

Comment: In Linux, your program is executed by shell with those arguments. I do not think it's possible to get it without reading memory of the shell. Edit: didn't know it was a Windows question.

Comment: I don't have a code related to this subject, that's the reason I am asking here, I tried few things that I mentioned in the post but none worked, tldr; there is no code it is just a question to build a code around because I can't start my code without this simple check

Comment: What you describe cannot be correct.  argv[0] points to the program name being run, and "HW01/n" is one argument.

Comment: @Salbert well please show us what didn't work and your attempt to read and examine the program arguments. No code: no question! A code to show the aguments can hardly be tldr;

Comment: @WeatherVane "Because I've checked if the space is added to the end of argv[0] or the the beginning of argv[1] but it wasn't there."   All I did was adding spaces and constantly checking the len(strlen) of argv[0] and argv[1]

Comment: That's right, it isn't there. If you put *three* spaces they are not there either, because the space(s) separate one argument from the next. They are only there if you enclose the extra spaces and the argument with quotes, such as `test " argument"`.

Comment: Try printing the args out completely.  Maybe arg[0] is the program name and arg[1] is the program name + arg[1] when no space.  I'm guessing by my memory of program invocation.

Answer (score 6):

What you want to do is not use argv.

Instead, use the function [GetCommandLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and parse the result yourself.

Comment: its not an option(I have to stick to the assignment's rules) but thanks anyways

Comment: @Salbert Please specify all rules that pertain the question.

Comment: @Salbert I cannot guess what the rules for your assignment are, you have to know that on your own.

Comment: Then I think the assignment is quite possibly flawed, I'm pretty sure argv based args come through based on space separator.